# Unable to change animation interpolation or extrapolation

Tags: animation, keyframes, interpolation

I'm new to Blender and I have a simple animation consisting of an empty object changing orientation around its Y axis about 30°. The steps to animate this:

1. Opened up timeline and set position to 0 (pos of keyframe 1)
2. Hovered over object's *Transform > Location* values box and hit <kbd>I</kbd> key (so that it highlights yellow), thus placing keyframe and pos 0
3. Moved to pos 60 on timeline (position of keyframe 2)
4. Changed orientation of object as desired
5. Hovered again over *Transform > Location* and hit <kbd>I</kbd>, placing keyframe 2.

When I hit play the object rotates with a bezier ease in and out. I want a linear interpolation, so I go to the dope sheet, highlight all keyframes, and hit <kbd>T</kbd> then select linear interpolation, but the animation remains with an ease in and out. I also go to *Channel > Extrapolation Mode* and choose *Linear* with no visible change.

My graph editor is completely flat and shows only 2 points (presumably the keyframes).

Screenshots for clarity: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJrkv.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guv9E.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1dtE.png)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to be changing *Extrapolation* mode, that is used for "extending" or repeating an animation after the last keyframe, as far as I know.

You are supposed to change the handle types, instead.

Select all your keyframes with <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>V</kbd> *Set Keyframe Handle Type > Vector*